# Showing only one AlertView in if-statement

Tags: ios, if-statement, uialertview

I'm busy making an application where I want an `UIAlerView` to be shown, if an coordinate hits one of the Polygon. 
I got the this, and it works fine:

```
    for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in myMapView.overlays)
    {
        if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
        {
            MKPolygon *polygon = (MKPolygon *)overlay;

            CGMutablePathRef mpr = CGPathCreateMutable();

            MKMapPoint *polygonPoints = polygon.points;

            for (int p=0; p < polygon.pointCount; p++)
            {
                MKMapPoint mp = polygonPoints[p];
                if (p == 0)
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
                else
                    CGPathAddLineToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
            }

            CGPoint mapPointAsCGP = CGPointMake(mapPointToTest.x, mapPointToTest.y);

            BOOL pointIsInPolygon = CGPathContainsPoint(mpr, NULL, mapPointAsCGP, FALSE);

            NSLog(@"Coordinate %f,%f is in polygon %@: %@",
                  coordinateToTest.latitude, coordinateToTest.longitude,
                  polygon.title,
                  (pointIsInPolygon ? @"Yes" : @"No"));

            if (pointIsInPolygon == 1) {
                   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Uw vuilnisdag" message:@"Op dinsdag 06:00 en vrijdag 06:00" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Stel notificatie in", nil];
                    [alertView show];
                } else {
                    UIAlertView *alertViewN = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Geen ophaaldag gevonden in uw gebied" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alertViewN show];
               }

            CGPathRelease(mpr);
        }
    }
```

In the for loop the `CGPathContainsPoint` code checks all `MKPolygon`. 
In the end I get a result: 1 or 0.

- 1 = means there is an point in one of the Polygons
- 0 = means there is no point found in one the Polygons

The problem now is that, if the result is 0, I get like 8 times an AlertView.
Is there an easy way to get rid of this?
Thanks

---

**Update 1**

This is the alert View delegate.
Not sure what value to put in buttonIndex == 0.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0 ){
        //
    }
}
```

---

**Update 2**

This is what I've got so far.
I was playing around with the `isKindOfClass:[NSString class]`.. Didn't worked out.

```
BOOL pointIsInPolygon = CGPathContainsPoint(mpr, NULL, mapPointAsCGP, FALSE);

            NSLog(@"Coordinate %f,%f is in polygon %@: %@",
                  coordinateToTest.latitude, coordinateToTest.longitude,
                  polygon.title,
                  (pointIsInPolygon ? @"Yes" : @"No"));

            if (pointIsInPolygon == 1) {
                pointIsInPolygon = TRUE;
                   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Uw vuilnisdag" message:@"Op dinsdag 06:00 en vrijdag 06:00" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Stel notificatie in", nil];
                //[alertView show];

                } else {
                    UIAlertView *alertViewN = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Geen ophaaldag gevonden in uw gebied" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    //[alertViewN show];
               }

            CGPathRelease(mpr);
        }
    }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    //this would be the yes button or cancel
    if (buttonIndex == 0 ){
        NSLog(@"ButtonIndex Okay");
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a boolean flag? BTW this is not related to Xcode.

Comment: How to set a boolean flag?

Comment: What are the alert views asking or saying?  Basically, don't show the alert views _inside_ the for-loop.  Instead, inside the for-loop keep track of the data you want to present and present one alert view _after_ the for-loop.  Also, with BOOL variables, say `YES` or `NO` instead of `1` or `0` (though that is not affecting the outcome, it's easier to read and understand).

Comment: The alertViewN says: "No collection date found in your area".

Comment: So if the coordinate is in _any_ of the polygons, you want to say "A" and if the coordinate is in _none_ of the polygons, you want to say "B".  Right?

Comment: Yes, Maybe it is a idea to do the outcome from `pointIsInPolygon` into an `NSString` and then make an if-statement from it?

Comment: Yes, almost like what the answer is saying: In the for-loop, record what you want to say.  After the for-loop, say it.

Comment: @DaxRahusen, I don't understand why you think you need to check the class.  Please do not take offense but it would be better if you started with some very simple apps and learn the basics of Objective-C and programming in general.

Comment: Finally fixed it Anna. I've set a `BOOL` to TRUE in the `if (pointIsInPolygon == 1)` Then outside the loop I did another `if-else statement` where I showed the `AlertViews`. Sorry again for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the alert view's delegate to `self` when you create it, and implement the delegate method that gets executed when the alert is dismissed. Also keep a reference to your alert view after presenting it.

In the alert view delegate method (after the user dismisses the alert view), reset the reference to `nil`. When your condition to show an alert view is met, show it only if the reference equals `nil`.

**EDIT**
In your particular case:

Where it says:

```
if (pointIsInPolygon == 1){
    // ...
}
```

Instead of showing the alert, set a flag to true. After you looped through all the eight elements, show only 1 alert if the flag is true.

Comment: Did the delegate to self. But I'm not clear what I need to do with the alert view delegate method? I know that if the user hits the 'Okay' button, it must return a value that stops the other alert views.
See the update in the post.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `(pointIsInPolygon == 0)`? Because we're talking about, what if the paramater is == 0, right? Still don't understand what you mean with setting a flag to true. I've been trying to change the `[alertView show];`, but get an ARC error. And do I still need to do the delegate method?

Comment: 1 or 0, doesn't matter. Your loop tests the condition 8 times, and you show an alert view right there and then, each time, so you end up showing 8 alert views in succession. Instead, set a boolean variable to TRUE every time the test passes, and after the loop ended, show only ONE alert if the boolean variable is TRUE.